# Playing with setw, cout and for

Tags: c++

Why this different behavior depending on if it's into a for statement or not, or if its a simple `cout << '*'` repeated three times or a `cout << "***"` ?

All the sentences has a setw(6), like the second and the eight line of the diamond, but not all has the same behavior, as you can see. Some starts output padding 6 spaces, other stats output padding 4 spaces.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

#include <iomanip>

using std::setw;

int main(){
    int ast = 1,
        pos = 5;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        cout << setw(pos);
        for(int j = 1; j <= ast; j++)
                cout << '*';
        if(i <= 4) {
            ast += 2;
            pos -= 1;
        }
        else {
            ast -= 2;
            pos += 1;
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }


    cout << '\n';

    cout << "cout << \"***\"\n";
    cout << setw(6);
    cout << "***";

    cout << '\n';

    cout << "for x3 cout << '*'\n";
    cout << setw(6);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) // this should look like the first for statement, but not
        cout << '*';

    cout << '\n';
    cout << "cout << '*' three times\n";
    cout << setw(6);
    cout << '*';
    cout << '*';
    cout << '*';
    cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output that I've got for this code:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *

cout << "***"
   ***
for x3 cout << '*'
     ***
cout << '*' three times
     ***
```

Also, isn't this:

```
 cout << setw(6);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        cout << '*';
```

The same as this?

```
cout << setw(6);
cout << '*';
cout << '*';
cout << '*';
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `width` of the stream is automatically reset (to zero) each time you call `operator <<`. So if you have a loop writing multiple values you have to use `setw` each time round the loop.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw

Answer (score 1):

For the following:

```
cout << setw(6);
cout << "***";
```

The `***` 'eats' 3 of the 6 spaces provided by `std::setw`.

But for:

```
 cout << setw(6);
 for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
      cout << '*';
```

and

```
cout << setw(6);
cout << '*';
cout << '*';
cout << '*';
```

the `*` only 'eats' one of the spaces. After that the `width` of the stream is reset when the next `cout <<` is called.

You wouldn't want any different behavior anyway as the alternative where the `width` was maintained would have yieled `*     *     *` for the last two examples.