# spacing issue of calender in c++

Tags: c++, calendar

i want to display the calender using single loop but the main issue is spacing am not able to give the right amount of spaces between them

```
cout << "M   T   W   TH   FRI   Sa   Su " << endl;

for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
{
    if (i % 7 == 0)
    {
        cout << i << endl << "  ";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << i << "   ";
    }
}

cout << endl;
```

my output

[image]

Comment: Is searching really that hard these days? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090676/playing-with-setw-cout-and-for) for example.

Comment: i want to display the dates but there is a spacing issue after i>9

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout<<endl<<" S  M  T  W  T  F  S"<<endl<<endl;
int k=1;
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
{
    if(k>31){break;}
    if(k<10){cout<<" "<<k++<<" ";}
    else{cout<<k++<<" ";}
}cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```